# Sending video data from python to nodejs

Tags: python, node.js, data-transfer

So basically I'm trying to send video data from a raspberry pi using a python script, to my node js server so I can use the footage on my website

I've tried to use urrlib (which didnt work for this) , and I've used the requests library as you can see below:

```
import requests
url = 'http://0f0730afe95f.ngrok.io/upload/'

#sending this commented dictionary worked , just an FYI
# data ={
#     "name": "morpheus",
#     "job": "leader"
# }


data = open('test.mp4','rb').read()
r = requests.request('POST',url, files={'media':data})
```

I had even tried specifying  `files= {'files':data}` which didn't work either

> Also there was no error with my post url , as the commented dictionary which I've put up above sent successfully
> Removing the .read() after open did not make any difference
> test.mp4 is in the same directory as the python script so there's no error with that either. The open method works, only the request does not get sent

Would appreciate any help on this
Thanks

Comment: you can reference the following url. It will help us, I think.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64416023/stream-continuous-data-from-a-python-script-to-nodejs